# Scala read a json file from gcs path

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-storage

I have json config file. How to read through scala when spark submit through spark.extra.JavaOptions -Dconfig.file=gcspath/file.json

Comment: What did you try so far? What's not working?